# Hide UICollectionView items in certain layouts

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionView` that uses a couple of different layouts depending on user preferences. I want certain cells to show up for some layouts but not for others. How do I accomplish this? Do I actually need to reload the collection view data?

Answer (score -1):

There are two steps to accomplishing this (which also works with `UITableView`).

1. Update the data source. If you're using an `NSDictionary` or `NSArray`, then you'll need to add or remove the items you want to show/hide.
2. Call `reloadData` on the `UICollectionView` or `UITableView`. That's pretty much it.

If you want to remove or add with an animation, that's different. There are a couple more methods in the middle that you have to call and make sure that your update sequence is correct. But that is a different question altogether.

**EDIT**:

As an example of how to use an array

```
- (void)methodCalledWhenLayoutChanges:(BOOL)includeOptionalString {
    if (includeOptionalString) {
        [_collectionViewDataSourceArray addObject:_optionalString];
    } else {
        [_collectionViewDataSourceArray removeObject:_optionalString];
    }

    [self.collectionView reloadData];
    }

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return _collectionViewDataSourceArray.count;
}

// Never actually setup a collection view like this. This is just an example of how to reference a data source for creating a collection view cell.
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [[UICollectionViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 50.0f, 50.0f)];

    UILabel *textLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:cell.bounds];
    textLabel.text = [_collectionViewDataSourceArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell addSubview:textLabel];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I'm hoping to have some items disappear when I change the layout, without having to change what is returned from the data source methods.

Comment: You shouldn't have to change what's returned from the data source methods (`cellForItemAtIndexPath`, `numberOfSectionsInCollectionView `, etc) but you will most likely need to change the content of the actual data source (remove an item from the array/dictionary representing the content).

Comment: How would the collection view and/or its layout know to remove the cells if it doesn't go through those methods?

Comment: You would call `reloadData` to call those methods again, but you wouldn't change those methods. How are you determining which cells show up? What does your `collectionView: numberOfItemsInSection:` method look like?

Comment: Have another reference to the array you use to populate the cells, That will be the filteredColletionViewDataSourceArray. when you change the layout, you reset the filtered array, adding only the items you want via your custom logic, then reload data. It's like implementing a search but with predefined results =)